# Combine two tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-5

I have the following query:

```
{
 SELECT A.Id, C1.FullName AS APerson, C2.FullName As BPerson
 FROM TableA AS A
   LEFT JOIN TableC AS C1 ON A.FK_PersonA = C1.Id
   LEFT JOIN TableC AS C2 ON A.FK_PersonB = C2.Id
 UNION
 SELECT B.Id, B.FullName1 AS APerson, B.FullName2 AS BPerson
 FROM TableB AS B
}
```

I would like to convert this to an Entity Framework lambda query, is this possible?

Data Model

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But, firstly format you sql code, and show your models.

Comment: it is possible. what effort have you made? code first or edmx?

Comment: I am using edmx derived from Database (DB first approach).  Not sure how to formatt query on SF, kind of new to SF.

Comment: Updated formatt.  Working on model.

Comment: @Alexander updated the question based on your comments

Comment: Entity A should have navigation properties to both C entities, so you get the joins for free. Please show the class model (not the data model) for us to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should create repositories for your models. Read about this [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
So , you can use this:

```
var ret = 
    (from taRec in TableA.GetAll()
    join tc1 in TableC.GetAll on taRec.FK_PersonA equals tc1.Id
      into tcRecs1
    from tcRec1 in tcRecs1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join tc2 in TableC.GetAll on taRec.FK_PersonB equals tc2.Id
      into tcRecs2
    from tcRec2 in tcRecs2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        taRec.Id, APerson = tcRec1.FullName, BPerson = tcRec2.FullName
    }).Union(
        from tbRec in TableB.GetAll()
        select new {
            tbRec.Id, APerson = tbRec.FullName, BPerson = tbRec.FullName
    });
```

Comment: Old winform software repository pattern was not planned up front so I cannot change.

Comment: Use another pattern, i showed you how to use linq query. And in your desc no information about used patterns and EF models.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework and lambda based queries, this is stated in my question.  I am not using any other patterns.  I think I can convert what you provided into a EF lambda based query.

Comment: _Firstly you should create repositories_. That's overkill in the context of this question. Entity framework has repositories, they're called DbSet.